# Error While Registering In Laravel 5.6

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have an error while i want to register in the app. I had a table registers which i deleted it. When i wanted to register, all data went to that table. Now i want them to go to users table and i have the following functions and model. But when i submit the info to be registered, this error pops out

```
QLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '24gardi.registers' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `registers` where `username` = amirhosseingheibi@gmail.com)
```

This is the controller:

```
public function ShowRegisterForm()
    {
        $title = "ثبت نام";
        return view('register')->with('title', $title);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validation2($request);
        $register = User::create([
            'username' => $request->input('username'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('username')),
            'register_type' => $request->input('username'),
            'first_name' => $request->input('username'),
            'last_name' => $request->input('username'),
            'gender' => $request->input('username'),
            'email' => $request->input('username'),
            'mobile' => $request->input('username'),
            'national_id' => $request->input('username'),
            'personnel_pic' => $request->input('username'),
            'contract_pic' => $request->input('username'),
            'national_id_pic' => $request->input('username'),
            'profile_pic' => $request->input('username')
        ]);
        if ($register) {
            return redirect('/')->with('success', 'ثبت نام با موفقیت انجام شد.');
        }
        return redirect('/register')->with('errors', 'ثبت نام با موفقیت انجام نشد.');
    }

    public function validation2($request)
    {
        return $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|unique:registers|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|max:255',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'national_id' => 'required|unique:registers|max:10',
            'gender' => 'required|max:5',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:registers|max:255',
            'mobile' => 'required|max:13'
        ]);
    }
```

This is the route (the named route is the one getting used in the form in view):

```
Route::Get('/register', 'UsersController@ShowRegisterForm');
Route::Post('/register', 'UsersController@register')->name('custom.register');
```

And this is the model(and yes i have added use App\User (the model for users table) in the controller called UsersController):

```
protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'register_type',
        'username',
        'password',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'national_id',
        'gender',
        'mobile',
        'email',
        'personnel_pic',
        'national_id_pic',
        'contract_pic',
        'profile_pic',
        'score'
    ];

    public function tours ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tour');
    }

    public function comments ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function suggestions ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Suggestion');
    }


    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
    ];
```

What im trying to say is that i dont undrestand why the error pops out. Please if anyone knows what the error is help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing to a wrong table in your in Validations()

```
 public function validation2($request)
    {
        return $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|max:255',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'national_id' => 'required|unique:users|max:10',
            'gender' => 'required|max:5',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
            'mobile' => 'required|max:13'
        ]);
    }
```

Read more about validations [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)

Comment: O wow! I feel terribly dumb! Thanks for your answer again! However, I learned this time how to properly ask a question :D. I want to accept the answer but it says I can't until 11 minutes later.

Comment: @Capt.BlackBearD Welcome to SO then

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `unique:registers` in the `validation2` method to
`unique:users`